# Determine for each possible values of x if series converges or diverges. Identify interval of convergence and the radius of convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Here is the math problem:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi+1}{4}\right)\frac{x^n}{n^5}$$

I'm trying to find the interval of convergence and radius of convergence for this problem.

Usually, I'd apply either the ratio test, or root test, then pull out all the terms with an $x$, then calculate the limit of the terms surrounding an $n$. However, in this case, with the $\sin$, I'm not sure how to.

I'd share what I have done so far, except, I just don't know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

If it helps, we have not yet reached Maclauren or Taylor series in our maths class yet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE.  As a hint $\sin\big(\frac{2n\pi+1}{4}=\pm \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

Comment: @Khosrotash Oh! I kind of suspected something like this! I solved by making that sin equal to either + or - √2/2 and then ratio tested it. This got the solve as |x| * 1 (so radius of convergence is 1), then the interval of convergence as -1 < x < 1. Is this right? Thanks for your tip!!

Comment: @Khosrotash Edit: -1 <= x <= 1 and radius of 1. That should be right?

Comment: @Khosrotash Also, the hint is wrong I think, now that I'm looking after I solved it. sin((2npi + 1)/4) does not equal +- root(2)/2

Answer (score 2):

The $\sin(\frac {2n\pi+ 1}{4})$ is irrelevant.  In fact, it is a constant and can be pulled out front.

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\sqrt [n]{\frac {x^n}{n^5}} = x$

The radius of convergence is $|x| = 1$